# Automated testing of user mode actions on TFS Build Agent

Tags: c#, unit-testing, tfs, keyboard

I am writing an application that responds to keyboard actions.  To automate testing, I wrote a keyboard simulator that uses User32.dll / SendInput to automate key presses and releases.  This approach works fine on the local developer machine, but fails when checked-in and run on a TFS build agent.  My guess is that the user mode activities are not getting processed as expected because it is being run as a service.  Is there a way to automate keyboard presses and releases that is compatible with automated testing as a service?

Setup:
Hosted TFS (tfspreview.com)
Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate
MSTest, xUnit.NET
Windows 7 Pro (dev)
Windows 2008 R2 (build controller / build agent)

Offending code:

Test case:

```
            KeyboardSimulator.PressKey(Keys.A);
```

Keyboard Simulator:

```
    public static void PushKeyDown(Keys key)
    {
        SendKeyboardInput(key, (uint)FLAGS.NONE);
    }

    public static void ReleaseKey(Keys key)
    {
        SendKeyboardInput(key, (uint)FLAGS.KEYUP);
    }

    public static void PressKey(Keys key)
    {
        PushKeyDown(key);
        ReleaseKey(key);
    }

    #region Internals

    private static KEYBDINPUT createKeybdInput(Keys key, uint flag)
    {
        KEYBDINPUT i = new KEYBDINPUT();
        i.wVk = (ushort)key;
        i.wScan = 0;
        i.time = 0;
        i.dwExtraInfo = IntPtr.Zero;
        i.dwFlags = flag;
        return i;
    }

    private static void SendKeyboardInput(Keys key, uint flag)
    {
        INPUT[] inputs = new INPUT[1];
        inputs[0].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
        inputs[0].ki = createKeybdInput(key, flag);
        uint intReturn = SendInput(1, inputs, System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.SizeOf(inputs[0]));
        if (intReturn != 1) throw new ApplicationException("Could not send key");
    }

    [DllImport("User32.dll")]
    private static extern uint SendInput(uint numberOfInputs, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, SizeConst = 1)] INPUT[] input, int structSize);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Team Foundation Build server runs as a Windows Service by default. As you guessed, **this means that it can't interact with the desktop** (it doesn't have one).

You'll need to configure your build service to run in **interactive mode**. Follow these steps:

1. Open the TFS administration console,
2. Select Build Configuration,
3. Click Properties on your BuildService
4. Select `Run build service as: Interactive Process`

Of course, you'll need to remain logged onto that machine for the duration. If it's a separate build server, you can configure automatic logon and add `TfsBuildServiceHost.exe` to the automatic startup list. With this configuration, you shouldn't need to logon to it again.

Comment: That fixed it Grant.  It was the answer I was expecting, but not the one I was hoping for.  It's not a huge deal since it is running as a VM on my developer machine.  There's just something about a server with a logged on user that makes me feel dirty.  But... at least... GREEN BAR!